# Why is WebElement the same using for each loop Selenium?

Tags: java, selenium

I'm trying to get  elements using `for each` loop, but I'm gettting always the same first element.

Firstly, I'm searching for an element by `id`.

```
WebElement tableId = driver.findElement(By.id("tablepress-6"));
```

Then I'm going to find `tr` elements by `tagName`.

```
 List<WebElement> trElements = tableId.findElements(By.tagName("tr"));
```

And finally using `for each` loop, I'm trying to get `td` elements with required fields:

```
List<Journal> journalList = new ArrayList<>();
    //...
    for (WebElement element : trElements) {
    String title = element.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"tablepress-6\"]/tbody/tr/td[3]")).getText();
    //String title = element.findElement(By.xpath("//table[@id='tablepress-6']/tbody/tr/td/a")).getText();
    String city = ...;
    journalList.add(new Journal(title, city));
    }
```

As a result I'm getting:

```
Journal{title='Low Temperature Physics', city='...'}
Journal{title='Low Temperature Physics', city='...'}
Journal{title='Low Temperature Physics', city='...'}
Journal{title='Low Temperature Physics', city='...'}
```

Instead of the expected:

```
Journal{title='Low Temperature Physics', city='...'}
Journal{title='Ukrainian Journal of Physical Optics', city='...'}
Journal{title='Theoretical and Experimental Chemistry', city='...'}
Journal{title='Kinematics and Physics of Celestial Bodies', city='...'}
```

Here's my HTML code:

```
<table id=tablepress-6 class="tablepress tablepress-id-6">
    <thead>
        <tr class="row-1 odd">
            <th class=column-1>Sci</th>
            <th class=column-2>Subject area (SJR)</th>
            <th class=column-3>Назва наукового журналу</th>
            <th class=column-4>ISSN (Print&amp;El)</th>
            <th class=column-5>Scopus(SNIP)</th>
            <th class=column-6>WOS_Core</th>
            <th class=column-7>Місто</th>
            <th class=column-8>Шифри 2015</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody class=row-hover>
        <tr class="row-2 even">
            <td class=column-1>П</td>
            <td class=column-2>Physics and astronomy</td>
            <td class=column-3><a href="http://ltp.aip.org/" target=_blank rel="nofollow noopener noreferrer">Low Temperature Physics</a></td>
            <td class=column-4>1063-777X
                <br/> 1090-6517
                <br/>
            </td>
            <td class=column-5><a href="https://www.scopus.com/sourceid/13789" target=_blank rel="nofollow noopener noreferrer">0,617</a>
                <br/> 1997-2019
            </td>
            <td class=column-6><a href="http://ip-science.thomsonreuters.com/cgi-bin/jrnlst/jlresults.cgi?PC=MASTER&amp;ISSN=1063-777X" target=_blank rel="nofollow noopener noreferrer">SCIE (0,860)</a>
                <br/> 1997-2019
            </td>
            <td class=column-7>Харків /
                <br/> Нью-Йорк
            </td>
            <td class=column-8>10; 13</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="row-3 odd">
            <td class=column-1>П</td>
            <td class=column-2>Physics and astronomy</td>
            <td class=column-3><a href="http://www.ifo.lviv.ua/journal/" target=_blank rel="nofollow noopener noreferrer">Ukrainian Journal of Physical Optics</a>
                <br/> Український журнал фізичної оптики</td>
            <td class=column-4>1609-1833
                <br/> 1816-2002
                <br/>
            </td>
            <td class=column-5><a href="https://www.scopus.com/sourceid/11400153315" target=_blank rel="nofollow noopener noreferrer">0,593</a>
                <br/> 2000-2019
            </td>
            <td class=column-6><a href="http://ip-science.thomsonreuters.com/cgi-bin/jrnlst/jlresults.cgi?PC=MASTER&amp;ISSN=1609-1833" target=_blank rel="nofollow noopener noreferrer">SCIE (0,488)</a>
                <br/> 2008-2019
            </td>
            <td class=column-7>Київ</td>
            <td class=column-8>10</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="row-4 even">
            <td class=column-1>П</td>
            <td class=column-2>Chemistry</td>
            <td class=column-3><a href="http://link.springer.com/journal/11237" target=_blank rel="nofollow noopener noreferrer">Theoretical and Experimental Chemistry</a></td>
            <td class=column-4>0040-5760
                <br/> 1573-935X
                <br/>
            </td>
            <td class=column-5><a href="https://www.scopus.com/sourceid/21969" target=_blank rel="nofollow noopener noreferrer">0,198</a>
                <br/> 1967-2019
            </td>
            <td class=column-6><a href="http://ip-science.thomsonreuters.com/cgi-bin/jrnlst/jlresults.cgi?PC=MASTER&amp;ISSN=0040-5760" target=_blank rel="nofollow noopener noreferrer">SCIE (0,878)</a>
                <br/> 2008-2019
            </td>
            <td class=column-7>Київ /
                <br/> Нью-Йорк
            </td>
            <td class=column-8>10; 16</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="row-5 odd">
            <td class=column-1>П</td>
            <td class=column-2>Earth and planetary sciences; Physics and Astronomy</td>
            <td class=column-3><a href="http://www.allertonpress.com/journals/kin.htm" target=_blank rel="nofollow noopener noreferrer">Kinematics and Physics of Celestial Bodies</a>
                <br/> Кінематика і фізика небесних тіл</td>
            <td class=column-4>0884-5913
                <br/> 1934-8401
                <br/>
            </td>
            <td class=column-5><a href="https://www.scopus.com/sourceid/19700173017" target=_blank rel="nofollow noopener noreferrer">0,432</a>
                <br/> 2009-2019
            </td>
            <td class=column-6><a href="http://ip-science.thomsonreuters.com/cgi-bin/jrnlst/jlresults.cgi?PC=MASTER&amp;ISSN=0884-5913" target=_blank rel="nofollow noopener noreferrer">SCIE (0,654)</a>
                <br/> 2008-2019
            </td>
            <td class=column-7>Київ /
                <br/> Нью-Йорк
            </td>
            <td class=column-8>10</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="row-6 even">
            <td class=column-1>П</td>
            <td class=column-2>Biochemistry, genetics and molecular biology; Medicine</td>
            <td class=column-3><a href="https://link.springer.com/journal/11956" target=_blank rel="nofollow noopener noreferrer">Cytology and Genetics</a>
                <br/> Цитологія і генетика</td>
            <td class=column-4>0564-3783
                <br/> 0095-4527
                <br/>
            </td>
            <td class=column-5><a href="https://www.scopus.com/sourceid/19061" target=_blank rel="nofollow noopener noreferrer">0,229</a>
                <br/> 2009-2019
            </td>
            <td class=column-6><a href="http://ip-science.thomsonreuters.com/cgi-bin/jrnlst/jlresults.cgi?PC=MASTER&amp;ISSN=0095-4527" target=_blank rel="nofollow noopener noreferrer">SCIE (0,239)</a>
                <br/> 2007-2019
            </td>
            <td class=column-7>Київ /
                <br/> Нью-Йорк
            </td>
            <td class=column-8>09; 22</td>
        </tr>
     //...
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Am I missing something here? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try below XPath

........................

```
List<WebElement> trElements = tableId.findElements(By.xpath("./tbody/tr"));
```

.......................

```
String title = element.findElement(By.xpath("./td[3]")).getText();
```

Comment: Just tried it. For now it doesn't work: `Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":".//*[@id="tablepress-6"]/tbody/tr/td[3]"}`

Comment: I just changed two xpath a bit

Comment: Thanks, Bathiya, now it looks like what I need. A bit strange that it doesn't work using my code example.

Comment: It can be even improved like: `By.xpath("./td[3]/a")`

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively You can do that in a single `xpath` statement.

```
List<WebElement> Elements = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//table[@id='tablepress-6']/tbody//tr//td[3]/a"));

 List<Journal> journalList = new ArrayList<>();

    for (WebElement element : Elements) {
    String title = element.getText();

    String city = ...;
    journalList.add(new Journal(title, city));
    }
```